# Eager loading not working in L4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, eager-loading

I have the following tables:

**users**

```
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username', 30);
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->string('remember_token')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**organisations**

```
    Schema::create('organisations', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique('name');
        $table->integer('owner_id')->unsigned()->index()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('owner_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and I have the following **Organisation** Eloquent model:

```
class Organisation extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
     */
    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'owner_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

I am trying to use `Eager Loading` functionality of `Eloquent` ORM like this in my controller:

```
public function index()
{
    return View::make('organisations.index')
        ->with('organisations', Organisation::with('user')->all());
}
```

When I do this, I get the following exception error:

## Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()

Any idea why this isn't working? Am I using the eager loading incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`all()` is a static method in the `Model` class, you can only use it like this: `Model::all()`.
You need to use `get()` to execute your query.

```
Organisation::with('owner')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks. This almost worked. What I needed was this: `Organisation::with('owner')->get();` as my `belongsTo` relationship was defined in the `owner()` method on the `Organisation` model.

Comment: A yes. I honestly wasn't even looking at your relations. I only saw the error and your call and knew what the problem was ;)